# Wcf Rest Service Method Returns Errors Unable to Cast Object Of Type

Tags: angularjs, linq, rest, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Rest Service into Angular JS Web Application. I am posting multi request from angular js application to wcf . When i post the request to wcf service i got following errors in console application .

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.String]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:**

Here is the Linq Query ..

```
 public bool cheekCreditScore(Credit_Crad credit)
        {
            int i = 600;
            //int j = 700;
            //int k = 800;
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var query = (from x in context.Credit_Score
                             where x.Account_Holder_First_Name == credit.account_first_name && x.Account_Holder_First_Name == credit.account_last_name
                             select x.Credit_Score1);
                if ((Convert.ToDouble(i) < Convert.ToDouble(query)))//**Error on this line**
                {


                    return true;


                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is screen shot on debugging mode ..

[image]

Here is the screen shot when i run the application .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns credit score of all the account holders(assuming a worst case where two or more account holder has same name ), hence you need to narrow it down to single or first result.

```
 var query = (from x in context.Credit_Score
              where x.Account_Holder_First_Name == credit.account_first_name          
              && x.Account_Holder_First_Name == credit.account_last_name
             select x.Credit_Score1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: False I don't think so. Null or false, can you be specific?